# Diffing many geometries from single area

Tags: java, jts-topology-suite, differences, jvm

Using the [JTS](https://github.com/locationtech/jts) library, I create a square `Geometry` representing water and diff from it large numbers of geometries representing land. At high zooms (think, Scandinavia), this can take a long time. Most of the geometries are small and of the same order of magnitude, so you might think each operation should take the same amount of time. Plotting the running time of the sequential diff operations, I get the following chart:

[image: processing time],

indicating diff processing time being very much dependent on its place in the sequence. My two current hypotheses:

- The original water Geometry becomes more and more complex as additional Geometries are being removed, leading to larger subsequent runtimes.
- Considering the two drop offs (/discontinuities) in running time as seen in the graph, I am reminded of Java garbage collection and perhaps the large number of objects is also playing a role.

Can you provide any insights?

---

Update:

Suggested in the comments was to perform unions instead of diffs. This resulted in a ~20% reduction in runtime, but not sufficient for our needs. The union operations also showed similar increases in running time after each subsequent union but with a smaller slope:

[image]

Regarding the suggestion to use the new overlay, unfortunately due to dependency hell I can't upgrade yet, but perhaps in a future iteration.

Conclusion: Still seeking ways to reduce runtime when dealing with large numbers of geometries (on the order of ~5000 with a total of ~180000 points).

Comment: Did you test with the new overlay https://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.com/2020/05/jts-overlay-next-generation.html?

Comment: did you try unioning the land polygon and doing one diff?

Answer (score 1):

To improve efficiency, you could consider **partitionning** your problem:

Decompose your area of interest into several zones, run the process on these zones and re-unite the result.

For your case, you could consider decomposing the input square into 4, for each of them, select the land polygons intesecting them (with a spatial index why not), running the union/diff on that. In the end, you could simply union the result of the 4 squares.

This partionning can be automated, and even made recursive, relying on a quadtree structure. Here is an example:
https://github.com/eurostat/JGiscoTools/blob/master/modules/algobase/src/main/java/eu/europa/ec/eurostat/jgiscotools/algo/base/Partition.java
which could be somehow reused...